# what's the recommended way to copy non-compiled rust assets to target

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

What is the recommended way to copy non-compiled rust application assets such as `HTML` and image files to the build target directory.

In particular, is placing a `build.rs` script in the project root and manually coding those actions truly the recommended method?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve, should the assets be included in the binary or externally available at runtime?

Comment: Included in the binary. (Sorry for the delayed response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are macros, [`std::include_bytes!(file_path)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_bytes.html) and [`std::include_str!(file_path)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_str.html), for incorporating the contents of files into the compiled binary. (However, the documentation is not explicit about the incorporation part though).

There are a number of [additional standard macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/index.html#macros).